# Replace value with related value

Tags: php, sql

I have a table which shows the details of galleries, each entry has a Gallery_ID, one of the fields is gallery_parent which is 0 if the record has no parent and then number of its parent if it does.

```
ID| Name      | parent
1 | gallery A | 0
2 | gallery B | 0
3 | gallery C | 0
4 | gallery D | 1
5 | gallery E | 2
```

How can I replace the parent gallery number with the parent gallery name?

Comment: Are you trying to change the schema of your database?  Or do you just want to see the parent name for each gallery?

Comment: what do you want to do? `UPDATE` or `SELECT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need two join the table to itself using `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT  a.ID,
        a.Name,
        b.Name as ParentName               //-- you can apply COALESCE here
FROM    tableName a
        LEFT JOIN   tableName b
            ON a.parent = b.id
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e222a/1)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*with COALESCE*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e222a/2)

Comment: I think he needs to replace not to select

Comment: @ErdinçÇorbacı I was thinking about it, *but I also think he wants to only select* because  he cannot update the field with varchar if it's numeric unless he wants to change the schema first.

Comment: ha ya beat me too it.  Removed my answer as the above should get you what you're looking for.

Comment: @ErdinçÇorbacı when you hear the word *REPLACE*, it doesn't really mean you want to update the record :D

Comment: Yes, I have all the data from the inital select I just want to replace parent number with its name

Comment: No, just want to show the name of the parent rather than its ID, thats all, just a replace for the client to see so it makes sence to them.

Comment: @TonyHanks yeah, that's what I'm doing, did you click the fiddle link and seen the results?

Comment: Yes, I just realise what the SQLFiddle Demo is, new to site, very clever, thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Above answer shows how to select the data and if you do want to update and if the parent is a varchar, you can do the following

```
UPDATE gal t1
LEFT JOIN gal t2 ON t1.parent=t2.ID
SET t1.parent = t2.name
```